# How to disable deselection when tapping the background in cytoscape.js?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I want my graph nodes not to be unselected when the user taps on the background.

From the [docs](https://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/gestures) of cytoscape.js I read

> Gestures
>
> Cytoscape.js supports several gestures:
>
> - ...
> - Tap background to unselect : desktop
> - ...
>
> All gesture actions can be controlled by the programmer, toggling them on or off whenever needed.

I however cannot find any option to toggle that gesture off. I tried to hook up the `tap` event and tried to cancel the event, but to no success.

```
cy.on('tab', ev => {
    if (ev.target === cy) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

How to prevent unselection on tab background?

Comment: experiment with https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.autounselectify

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for a solution, I found [this closed(answered) issue on the Cytoscape.js GitHub](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/2553). [Simon Golm's solution](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/2553#issuecomment-635192622) worked for me:

> ```js
> // Prevents the unselection of nodes when clicking on the background
> cy.on('click', (event) => {
>   if (event.target === cy) {
>     // click on the background
>     cy.nodes().unselectify();
>   } else {
>     cy.nodes().selectify();
>   }
> });
> ```